# Indent guide plugin for gedit (python)

Tags: python, plugins, indentation, komodo

[screenshot http://www.activestate.com/padfiles/komodo_edit/komodo_edit_linux.png](http://www.activestate.com/padfiles/komodo_edit/komodo_edit_linux.png)

See the indent guides? They're *damn* helpful when writing Python code. Any chance I could get something similar for `gedit`? I wouldn't mind having to write my own plugin, as long as it's in Python... So:

1. Is there a plugin for this which works with `gedit`?
2. If not, would it be possible to write one in *Python*.

Comment: To help you with your search, those are called "indent guides" or "indentation guides". HTH

Comment: :sigh: I guess I'll have to check the gedit repos and do something myself (in C, it doesn't appear possible in Python)

Comment: look at gtksourceview documentation. You can do it in python: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo
Best solution -> ditch gedit, get geany :)

Comment: Indent guides a la Notepad++ would be nice.

Comment: @aviraldg Did you end up writing such a plugin?

Comment: @trusktr No; I switched to Sublime Text 2. It's much better than Gedit.

Comment: Wow, it looks very nice indeed. I never saw it before. It must be fairly new...

Comment: @trusktr Search for "Package Control", install it and check out some of the plugins; that's where its real power lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a huge list of GEdit plugins here:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins

I haven't looked through them in a while, but I don't remember any implementing indentation guides. Many plugins are written in Python, so there are some good examples if you want to implement your own.